# How to avoid High Download charges when we pull docker images on cloud builds

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-billing, google-cloud-registry

We are building our stack on google cloud builds and for building we are using custom docker base images which are stored in *gcr.io/project-name/image-name*

While using this method we are e getting charged on **Download Worldwide Destinations (excluding Asia & Australia)**

Is there any way that we can reduce the High download charges? if we will run cloud builds and pull docker images from same region i.e. running docker build on `us-central1` and pulling docker image from `us-central1-docker.dev.pkg/project-name/image-name` will it reduce the download charges (No charge) ?

As we found one ref : https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-buckets

Or is there any other solution ?

Comment: I think using the same region will reduce costs a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on @John Hanley's comment, according to this documentation on [location considerations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/locations#considerations):

> A good location balances latency, availability, and bandwidth costs for data consumers.

Choosing the closest and same region will help optimize latency and network bandwidths. It would also be convenient to choose the region where it contains the majority of your data users.

There is a [Cloud Storage Always Free usage limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#cloud-storage-always-free) wherein **1GB Network Egress is free from North America to each GCP egress destination (excluding Australia and China)** however starting October 1, 2022, it would be upgraded to **100GB** You can check the full documentation on [Changes to Always Free usage limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing-announce#always-free).